# Multi-marginal optimal transport

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, optimal-transportation

The notion of Wasserstein distance between two probability measures is well-studied and well-motivated in many different branches of math and stat. 
Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be any two probability measures over a space $\mathcal{X}$ and let $\mathcal{M}(\mu,\nu)$  be the set of all couplings of $\mu$ and $\nu$. For a given metric $d$ over $\mathcal{X},$ the Wasserstein distance is defined as:

$$W(\mu, \nu):=\min_{(X,Y)\sim \pi\in \mathcal{M}(\mu,\nu)} \mathbb{E}d(X,Y)~.$$

The well-known Kantorovich duality states that

$$W(\mu, \nu)=\sup_{Lip(f)\leq 1} \mathbb{E}_{\mu}f(X)-\mathbb{E}_\nu[f(X)],$$
where supremum is taked over all 1-Lipschitz functions, i.e. $f:\mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq d(x, y)$ for all $x, y\in \mathcal{X}$.

In many different applications, it is favorable to find a similar quantity given $m$ probability measures. Let $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_m$ be $m$ probability measures on $\mathcal{X}$. The following is defined (for example see [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0026))  as the multi-marginal version of the above

$$W_{(m)}(\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_m):=\min \mathbb{E}_{\pi}c(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m)~,$$
where $c$ is a continuous "cost" function and the infimum is taken over all joint measures $\pi$ on $\mathcal{X}^m$ whose marginals are $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_m$.

I have been trying to find a Kantorovich-like dual formula for $W_{(m)}$.
Has it been studied before? Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

In general, under regularity conditions such as compactness, one can use standard minimax duality argument ($\min_y\max_x F(x,y)=\max_x\min_y F(x,y)$ -- for bilinear or, more generally, concave-convex functions $F$) to quickly show that 
\begin{multline}
 W(\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_m):=\inf_\gamma\int c d\gamma \\
 =\inf_\gamma^*\sup_{f_1,\dots,f_m}^*\Big(
 \int c(x) \gamma(dx)
 +\sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i d\mu_i-\sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i(x_i) \gamma(dx)
 \Big) \\ 
 =\sup_{f_1,\dots,f_m}^*\inf_\gamma^*\Big(
 \int c(x) \gamma(dx)
 +\sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i d\mu_i-\sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i(x_i) \gamma(dx)
 \Big) \\ 
 =\sup
 \sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i d\mu_i,  
\end{multline}
where $\inf_\gamma$ is taken over all probability measures $\gamma$ with marginals $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_m$, $\inf\limits_\gamma^*$ is taken over all (nonnegative) measures $\gamma$ on $\mathcal{X}^m$, 
$\sup\limits_{f_1,\dots,f_m}^*$ is taken over all appropriately integrable real-valued measurable functions $f_1,\dots,f_m$ on $\mathcal{X}$, 
$\sup$ is taken over all such functions $f_1,\dots,f_m$ on $\mathcal{X}$ that satisfy the condition 
\begin{equation}
 c(x)\ge \sum_{j=1}^m f_i(x_i)\text{ for all }x\in\mathcal{X}^m, 
\end{equation}
$x=(x_1,\dots,x_m)$, $dx=dx_1\times\dots\times dx_m$.
The second equality above follows because 
\begin{multline}
 \sup_{f_1,\dots,f_m}^*\Big(
 \sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i d\mu_i-\sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i(x_i) \gamma(dx)
 \Big) \\
 =\begin{cases}
 0&\text{ if the marginals of $\gamma$ are $\mu_1, \mu_2, \dots, \mu_m$}, \\
 \infty&\text{ otherwise.}
 \end{cases}
\end{multline}
The third equality above is the minimax duality. 
The last equality there
follows because 
\begin{multline}
\inf_\gamma^*\Big(
 \int c(x) \gamma(dx)
-\sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i(x_i) \gamma(dx)
 \Big)  \\
 =\begin{cases}
 0&\text{ if $c(x)\ge \sum_{j=1}^m f_i(x_i)\text{ for all }x\in\mathcal{X}^m$}, \\
 -\infty&\text{ otherwise.}
 \end{cases}
\end{multline}

> So, in general $\sum_{j=1}^m \int f_i d\mu_i$ and the condition $c(x)\ge \sum_{j=1}^m f_i(x_i)$ for all $x\in\mathcal{X}^m$ replace, respectively, 
>   $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}f(X)-\mathbb{E}_\nu f(X)=\int f d\mu-\int f d\nu$ 
>   and the condition $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq d(x, y)$ for all $x, y\in \mathcal{X}$ 
>   in the definition of the Wasserstein distance.

Even in the case $m=2$, the reduction from two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ in the condition $c(x)\ge \sum_{j=1}^2 f_i(x_i)$ for all $x\in\mathcal{X}^2$ to one function $f$ in the condition $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq d(x, y)$ for all $x, y\in \mathcal{X}$ is based on the special properties of a metric, available only if $c=d$, a metric. This is how it is done: Suppose $d(x_1,x_2)\ge \sum_{j=1}^2 f_i(x_i)$ for all $x\in\mathcal{X}^2$, that is, $f(s):=\inf\limits_t[d(s,t)-f_2(t)]\ge f_1(s)$ for all $s$. Also, $f(s)\le d(s,s)-f_2(s)=-f_2(s)$ for all $s$, so that $f_1\le f$ and $f_2\le-f$ and hence 
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{j=1}^2 \int f_i\, d\mu_i\le \int f\, d\mu_1-\int f\, d\mu_2. 
\end{equation}
Also,
$$d(s,t)+f(t)=\inf\limits_u[d(s,t)+d(t,u)-f_2(u)]
\ge\inf\limits_u[d(s,u)-f_2(u)]=f(s)$$ 
and hence $d(s,t)\ge f(s)-f(t)$ for all $s,t$ or, equivalently, 
$|f(t)-f(s)|\le d(s,t)$ for all $s,t$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the answer is almost in the paper you linked. There the author refers to

> Duality theorems for marginal problems, Hans G. Kellerer, Zeitschrift für Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie und Verwandte Gebiete, November 1984, Volume 67, Issue 4, pp 399–432, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00532047

One dual problem is already stated on page one. If you are looking for a "Kantorovich-Rubinstein" dual problem  with Lipschitz-functions: I am not sure if such a thing exists - one uses the metric in an essential ways and I don't see anything that replaces this here…